# Visual studio shows "Access violation executing location 0xABC123" and I have no clue how to debug

Tags: c#, visual-studio, user-interface

I have a C# GUI application that I debug in Visual Studio 2019. Windows 10 64 bit PC. Every once in a while, after my program is done doing its task (using a windows COM object to process a bunch of data on my computer and push to a SQL server) and is just idling, after 5-10 minutes it will throw the exception. It is frustrating because I have no idea what is causing it and no idea how to go about investigating, as the GUI should just be idling, and Visual Studio doesn't seem to be pointing me to any particular line of code that has crashed. I've attached a screenshot of visual studio below. Any help on what may be causing this issue or just something to get me further along debugging would be appreciated.

[Visual Studio screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jpd1x.png)

Comment: That COM object is most likely involved in the problem. Probably, you've got a memory corruption somewhere, and when the garbage collector kicks in, the exception happens. You could try to explicitly force a GC after you've done using the COM object.

Comment: Can you try launch your IDE under administrative rights? Problem related only to Debug?Problem related only to VS?

Comment: You could enable native code debugging, then - if you are lucky - the call stack will tell you more.